# Restart CountDownTimer on click

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

I have a simple CountDownTimer that displays its content in a textView. I am trying to accomplish the following:

- during count down, the view is not clickable: `textview.setClickable(false);`
- after count down finish, if the user clicks the textview, the count down should restart.

So I try a combination of

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {//inside CountDownTimer
    view.setClickable(true);
}
```

and

```
textview.setOnClickListener(countAgain);
OnClickListener countAgain = new OnClickListener() {//inside activity

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //          counter.cancel();
        counter.start();
    }
};
```

But this is not doing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does `view` come from and why isn't it `textview`? Also, do you have `android:clickable="true"` in your xml for your `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Set onclick listener for that text view, make it clickable .
In onclicklistner, make textview as non-clickable( yourTextView.setclickable(false) ).
change the text view values as you want and every time check the value against 0. When it becomes zero, make the text view clickable( yourTextView.setclickable(true) ).